# Combining rows for selected columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

I need help with data manipulation. I have a big dataset that looks something like this.

```
df_old<- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id  var1  date       time       var2 var3 var4
 1  A     2006-08-20 09:00:00   X    R    V
 1  A     2006-08-20 09:05:00   Y    Q    U
 1  A     2006-09-25 10:00:00   Z    R    V
 2  A     2007-03-29 13:00:00   X    P    T
 2  A     2007-04-20 11:05:00   Y    Q    U
")
```

This is what I would like to do:

1. For each unique "id", I only want to filter the rows that have the earliest dates. Thus, in this example, I want to keep only row 1, row2 and row4.
2. Next, since, row 1 and row 2 have the same "id" and the same "date",I want to combine them so that one "id" corresponds to one row and one row corresponds to one "id".
3. I want to apply paste(...,sep="-") for rows only on selected columns. Specifically, I want to combine entries in row 1 and row 2 for columns "var2" and "var3" only. As for "var1", "time", and "var4", I only want to keep the first value.

This is how I want it to look like:

```
df_new <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id  var1  date       time       var2 var3 var4
 1  A     2006-08-20 09:00:00   X-Y  R-Q  V
 2  A     2007-03-29 13:00:00   X    P    T
")
```

Comment: Yes, all 3 steps are possible, and most probably you will find answers to all of them by searching. What have you tried, show some effort. **Hint**: use group_by, min, filter, again group_by, paste...

Comment: In `df_new` shouldn't time for id 2 be 13:00:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first modify `var2` and `var3`, then arrange by date and select only the first row with `slice`:

```
library(dplyr)    
df_old %>%
   group_by(id, date) %>%
   mutate(var2 = paste(unlist(var2), collapse = "-"),
          var3 = paste(unlist(var3), collapse = "-")) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   arrange(date) %>%
   slice(1)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great answer. I would like to ask a few questions.

Comment: If for instance, one of the values to be merged (pasted together) is a missing value, how do we go about doing this without NA appearing as NA after the merge. For instance for id=1, var3 is missing for the first row. So it would appear as NA. When I follow this method, the result would be NA - R. How do I solve this?

Comment: does this help? `df_old %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  mutate(var2 = paste(unlist(var2[!is.na(var2)]), collapse = "-"),
         var3 = paste(unlist(var3[!is.na(var3)]), collapse = "-")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  slice(1)`